# Windows 10 to ubuntu 20.04 xrdp not working

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp, rdp

ive looked through a bunch of different solutions and none are working for me so far. im trying to rdp from my main windows 10 rig to my side ubuntu machine. none of the options in xrdp have given me any luck, i tried making an xrdp.ini script, and some other things and now im just at a loss as to what the issue could be.

the message im getting is
"connecting to ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
login failed for display 0"

and this message is relatively consistent through Xorg, Xvnc, vnc-any, and  neutrinordp=any

ive tried them all with no luck, different ports from 3389 to 5939, firewalls off and on.... so i dont know the issue. if anyone has a solution id really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might to have a look at the following post (see http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15733)
The post provides a script that ease the installation and post configuration actions of xRDP software.  The script is specifically designed for Ubuntu using Gnome desktop interface

Important !  Please note that the same user account cannot be logged in locally on the machine and perform a remote connection at the same time.  You will need to ensure that the user account your are planning to use to perform the rdp connection is not logged on your Ubuntu machine

How to use the script
From a terminal console,

Step 1 - download the script

```
wget https://www.c-nergy.be/downloads/xrdp-installer-1.2.1.zip
```

Step 2 - Unzip it

```
unzip xrdp-installer-1.2.1.zip
```

Step 3 - make it executable

```
chmod +x xrdp-installer-1.2.1.sh
```

Step 4 - Execute the script (standard install mode)

```
./xrdp-installer-1.2.2.sh
```

Logoff and try to remote connect to your Ubuntu machine

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya